# MudBlazor: Prevent close when clicking outside dialog (on overlay)

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, mudblazor

Is it possible to prevent closing the MudBlazor dialog when clicking on the overlay (outside the dialog)? Or to run a Task when clicking on the overlay?

Comment: did You read the documentation ? https://mudblazor.com/components/dialog#configuration-per-dialog it is there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To prevent closing the dialog when clicking on the overlay, you need to set `DisableBackdropClick = true`

For example:

```
@inject IDialogService DialogService

<MudButton OnClick="@((e) => OpenDialog())"
           Variant="Variant.Filled"
           Color="Color.Primary">Show Dialog</MudButton>

@code 
{
    private void OpenDialog()
    {   
        DialogOptions options = new DialogOptions() { DisableBackdropClick = true };
        DialogService.Show<DialogUsageExample_Dialog>("Custom Options", options);
    }
}
```